# Looking for a simple way to grab a value from one HTML page and have it appear in another. example below:

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to grab the values from the 3 `inputs` with the id's `#rooms_amount_bedroom` `#rooms_amount_bathrooms` and `#rooms_amount_kitchens`

HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="room_type_wrap">

        <small class="counter_title counter_opacity1">Bedrooms</small>
        <hr class="counter_title_underline">
        <div class="counter_wrap">
            <div class="subtractRoom" onclick="minusOneBedrooms()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_down.png" alt="" class="counter_down_arrow">
            </div>
            <input type="number" class="room_count" id="rooms_amount_bedroom" autocomplete="off" value="0">
            <div class="addRoom" onclick="plusOneBedrooms()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_up_white.png" alt="" class="counter_up_arrow">
            </div>
        </div>

        <small class="counter_title counter_opacity2">Bathrooms</small>
        <hr class="counter_title_underline">
        <div class="counter_wrap">
            <div class="subtractRoom" onclick="minusOneBathrooms()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_down.png" alt="" class="counter_down_arrow">
            </div>
            <input type="number" class="room_count" id="rooms_amount_bathrooms" autocomplete="off" value="0">
            <div class="addRoom" onclick="plusOneBathrooms()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_up_white.png" alt="" class="counter_up_arrow">
            </div>
        </div>

        <small class="counter_title counter_opacity3">Kitchens</small>
        <hr class="counter_title_underline">
        <div class="counter_wrap">
            <div class="subtractRoom" onclick="minusOneKitchens()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_down.png" alt="" class="counter_down_arrow">
            </div>
            <input type="number" class="room_count" id="rooms_amount_kitchens" autocomplete="off" value="0">
            <div class="addRoom" onclick="plusOneKitchens()">
                <img src="./assets/images/arrow_up_white.png" alt="" class="counter_up_arrow">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="next_button__rooms" id="input_info" onClick="location.href='contact_form.html'">
            <img src="./assets/images/next_arrow.png" alt="" class="next_arrow_icon__rooms">
        </div>
```

and have them all display in a `<p>` with the id `#chosen_service__room_types`

```
            <div class="your_service_rooms_wrap">
                <h2 class="your_service_rooms">Rooms total</h2>
                <div class="room_type_wrap__maps">
                    <p id="chosen_service__room_types"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The current Javascript I've written only grabs and displays the input of 1 of these values `#rooms_amount_bedroom`

JS on page where i want to grab data:

```
        document.getElementById('input_info').addEventListener('click', function () {
            let val1 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_bedroom').value;
            let val2 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_bathrooms').value;
            let val3 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_kitchens').value;
            localStorage.setItem('input', val1, val2, val3)
        })
```

JS on page where i want to display data:

```
document.getElementById('chosen_service__room_types').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('input', val1, val2, val3);
```

I'm new to Javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass one value to `localStorage.setItem()` function.

Change

```
localStorage.setItem('input', val1, val2, val3)
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem('input1', val1);
localStorage.setItem('input2', val2);
localStorage.setItem('input3', val3);
```

and then retrieve these values using their keys

```
const value1 = localStorage.getItem('input1');
const value2 = localStorage.getItem('input2');
const value3 = localStorage.getItem('input3');
```

and finallay set them inside `p` element

```
document.getElementById('chosen_service__room_types')
           .innerHTML = `${value1} ${value2} ${value3}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store one object per key in localStorage.

```
localStorage.getItem('input', val1, val2, val3);     // this will not work
```

What you should do is either store these values separately:

```
localStorage.setItem("input1", val1);
localStorage.setItem("input2", val2);
localStorage.setItem("input3", val3);
```

Or you can combine all three values into a single json object:

```
let obj = {val1, val2, val3};
localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then when you want to retreive the data back:

```
let retreived = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Object and then store them to the localstorage. You can check this code.

```
document.getElementById('input_info').addEventListener('click', function (e) {e.preventDefault();
  let val1 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_bedroom').value;
  let val2 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_bathrooms').value;
  let val3 = document.getElementById('rooms_amount_kitchens').value;
  const values = {val1, val2, val3};
  document.getElementById('chosen_service__room_types').innerHTML = [...Object.values(values)]
  localStorage.setItem('input', JSON.stringify(values));
});

if(localStorage.getItem('input')) {
  const values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('input'));

  document.getElementById('chosen_service__room_types').innerHTML = [...Object.values(values)]
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://jsbin.com/kowixumaco/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sifat! It's nice to learn another way of doing this using ```localStorage```